# Opening File in php

Tags: php

I want to open the file in php.
But when i open a file using fopen() i got the error.
My code is given below.

```
<?php

chdir("/home/chintan/directory");

$fp = fopen("abc.txt","w");

if($fp == false)
{
echo "Error while opening file";
}

fwrite($fp,"Hi........");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

File is exist and file/directory has writable permission
and it is giving the error that i have print using echo.
I have tried using w+ but it it giving the same result

Comment: Does the file exist? Try `w+` as file mode.

Comment: the echo "Error while opening file";

Comment: How about checking on file/directory permission if it is writable..

Answer (score 0):

Check out your php.ini and set the following:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

This should show you the 'real' underlying error.

Comment: This guidance should be a comment under the question because it attempts to help the OP to provide a more complete question.  It does not offer a resolving technique.

Comment: @mickmackusa this was nearly 10 years ago. The rules weren't as extreme. If you want to improve this, make it better.

Comment: I don't think this post needs improving.  It just needs to be converted to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide '/' after working folder to access it
wrong :

```
chdir("/home/chintan/directory");
```

correct:

```
chdir("/home/chintan/directory/");
```

your code:

```
<?php
chdir("/home/chintan/directory/");

$fp = fopen("abc.txt","w");

if($fp == false)
{
echo "Error while opening file";
}

fwrite($fp,"Hi........");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

P.S:

**while php in safe mode ,it will not allow to change directory to unaccessible  directory due to safe mode restriction**

> the function simply fails without generating any kind of error
>   message.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)

Answer (score -1):

I always use FALSE, not false. A shorter way to write the comparison is `if (!$fp) {...}`. Both will work. If it's a theoretical question, well, in a sane world :) your code should work. I use NetBeans' Code Insight to get syntax suggestions and flag incorrect lines.

As a heads-up, your code needs an else clause around the code that writes to the file. Right now it writes to a file even if the fopen returns false. I mean FALSE. :)

Comment: This is not really an answer to this question, is it? What case you use for boolean false is really irrelevant.

Comment: @Evert, I'm not a server admin and so I don't enough about what configuration options there are to set up PHP so it doesn't work properly. ;) Perhaps some error level could be set to fail on wrong case, since the docs and Code Insight both use uppercase and nothing else. Anyway, userxx has confirmed this is not the issue.

Comment: Yes, but 'false' and 'FALSE' are both perfectly fine in PHP. It's ok if you didn't know the answer, but then don't answer :)